# Writing PHP function incorporating PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm struggling to rewrite the following function to use a a PDO statement rather than `mysql_*`. It is obviously part of a larger script but I am having trouble converting this section.

```
//// What I have so far

function db_scalar($sql, $dbcon2 = null) {
    if($dbcon2 ==''){
        $dbcon2 = $GLOBALS['dbcon'];
    }
    $query = $dbcon2->prepare($sql);
    if ($line = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))    {
        $response = $line[0];
    }
    return $response;
}
```

---

```
//// Original function

function db_scalar($sql, $dbcon2 = null) {
    if($dbcon2 ==''){
        $dbcon2 = $GLOBALS['dbcon'];
    }
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $dbcon2) or die(db_error($sql));
    if ($line = mysql_fetch_array($query))  {
        $response = $line[0];
    }
    return $response;
}

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: prepared statements need to have their parameters bound to them in PDO.

Comment: Following what Ohgodwhy said, to do it right you would pass in an array of arguments, loop through that array and bind them.

Comment: @Loz Cherone - No luck unfortunately. I'm getting a couple of error messages: `Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` (line 5) and `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object` (line 6)

Comment: @developerwjk - Any tips on how to implement that in this function?

Comment: @Loz Cherone - Sorry yes I got the same error for fetch, just forgot to point it out.